# Dynamically Adding Elements to Zend_Form + 500 error (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, element

I am trying to create a form where you can add textboxes to your form and submit them. I've found [this](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/) tutorial online but I always get the same error when I click on "Add".

> **ERROR**: POST http://www.namesite.com/library/newfield/format/html 500 (Internal Server Error)

I've tried several things but I don't know where this comes from.

Comment: A 500 error is returned by your webserver, in most cases it will write more information to it's log. Have you checked the webservers log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was given because my view (from my newfieldAction) was named "newfield.phtml" and it had to be "newfield.ajax.phtml".